# How to use class from different project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

IDE: VS 2010, C# .net,

I have two win projects in 1 solution,

ProjA, and ProjB

now ProjA contains classA.cs

```
namespace ProjA
{
    class ClassA
    {
        public static int aValue = 5;
    }
}
```

same way ProjB contains ClassB.cs

```
namespace ProjB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        public static int bValue = 10;  
    }
}
```

and here is FormA.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ProjB;

namespace ProjA
{
    public partial class FormA : Form
    {
        public FormA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int va = ProjB.ClassB.bValue;; //Here getting error.???
        }
    }
}
```

Error : Cannot resolve symbol ProjB

Hint: This Problem Is related to namespace, I am trying to access ClassB which is in ProjB from FormA which is in ProjA, Here ProjA and ProjB are the 2 winforms project in Same solution

---xxxx----------- THis problem has been solved.

but now I want to access ClassA.cs in FormB.cs (just reverse of above problem),

when I tried same way ProjB(RighClick) -> Add reference -> ProjName(Tab) ProjA(Click)

The new problem I am facing is its saying unable to add it will create circular dependency, Please suggest How to solve this issue.

I want to access ClassA.cs in ProjB->FormB.cs here FormB is in ProjB

Comment: Have you added a reference to `ProjB` in `ProjA`?

Comment: Your code should work by just using `ClassB.bValue;`

Comment: Yes I have added you can see in 3rd block of code in post using ProjB

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I refer to a project from another one in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306652/how-can-i-refer-to-a-project-from-another-one-in-c)

Comment: Create 3rd project where you will move your shared code for ProjA and ProjB and refer that project to both ProjA and ProjB.

Answer (score 0):

`ProjB` is the namespace, so it doesn't know which class to use. If they're in the same solution(package of projects), just use the classname `ClassB`.(Or `ProjB.ClassB.bValue`)

If your projects aren't in the same Solution, go to Project A, File->Add->Existing Project, and add ProjB.

Comment: What happens if you use ProjB.ClassB.bValue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new instance of class or make it static.
So this:

```
 namespace ProjB
{
public static class ClassB
{
  public static int bValue = 10;  
}
```

and then

```
int va = ClassB.bValue;
```

OR

```
int va = new ClassB().bValue;
```

Comment: @user3593678 make classB static.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have referenced correctly `ProjB` you just need to instatinate `classB` in `ProjA`:

```
using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using ProjB;

    namespace ProjA
    {
         ProjB.ClassB classb=new ProjB.ClassB();
        public FormA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ....
           classb.bValue=....//set desired valued
        }

        private void FormA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int va =classb.bValue;
        }
```

Comment: I updated the question, ClassB is not accessable because It is in ProjB and FormA is in projA

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with reference,

I added reference

Right click ProjA -> References -> Add Reference,  then I added ProjB.

And Problem resolved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your visual studio

1-) Right click to your solution

2-) Then open Properties of the solution..

In the properties page, on the left you'll see menus..

3-) Click to Project Dependencies

In Details of project Dependencies (right side of the page )

4-) Select your Project A from the DropDownList which has a label with "Project"

5-) Under the DropDownList Check (Mark as checked) the ProjectB

6-) Click to save / ok

This operation what you did, warns the compiler as so :

"When you start to build ProjectA, Before build/compile ProjectA First build/Compile ProjectB and then continue to build ProjectA"

or in another saying 
" Dear Compiler ! 
When you work with my ProjectA, You will need My ProjectB to do your work properly. 
So please also check my ProjectB.

Best Regards, Your Lovely Developer "

NOTE : Never circular reference (ProjectA depends to ProjectB and ProjectB depends to ProjectA) to eachother..this gets infinitive recursion error of the compiling your code..!

[Visual Representation of The VS2010-ProjectDependencies Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0M5f.jpg)